# linking succeeds with clang but not gcc (-llzma on Debian bullseye amd64)

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linker-errors, lzma

On Debian bullseye (testing), with these xz/lzma-related packages installed:

```
ii  liblzma-dev:amd64                     5.2.4-1+b1                           amd64
ii  liblzma5:amd64                        5.2.4-1+b1                           amd64
ii  lzma-dev                              9.22-2.1                             all
```

Clang generates a working `./a.out` without issue:

`$>gunzip < /usr/share/doc/liblzma-dev/examples/02_decompress.c.gz | sed -s 's/extern int/int' | clang -std=c18 -Wall -Wextra -x c -llzma -`

However, attempting to use gcc fails:

`$>gunzip < /usr/share/doc/liblzma-dev/examples/02_decompress.c.gz | sed -s 's/extern int/int' | gcc -std=c18 -Wall -Wextra -x c -llzma -`

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccl8uTG0.o: in function `init_decoder':
:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `lzma_stream_decoder'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccl8uTG0.o: in function `decompress':
:(.text+0x1e1): undefined reference to `lzma_code'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccl8uTG0.o: in fuction `main':
:(.text+0x4e4): undefined reference to `lzma_end'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

`g++ --version` reports `9.3.0-3`

`clang++ --version` reports `9.0.1-10`

(Those compilers are both installed via `apt-get`.)

`/etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu.conf` contains

```
# Multiarch support
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

I have checked that `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.2.4` (and its `.so.5` and `.so` symlinks, and the associated .a file too) exist.

Furthermore, the output of `readelf --symbols /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.2.4 | grep 'lzma_[sec]'` shows that those three symbols exist (along with many others):

```
    67: 000000000000c720   106 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 lzma_stream_decoder@@XZ_5.0
   108: 00000000000039d0   701 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 lzma_code@@XZ_5.0
   117: 0000000000003c90    65 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 lzma_end@@XZ_5.0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `- -llzma` instead of `-llzma -`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clang puts the `-llzma` outside the `--as-needed` area of the linker command line:

```
[…] -L/usr/lib -llzma /tmp/--e00a22.o -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s […]
```

GCC puts it after `--as-needed`:

```
[…] --as-needed -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 […]
  -llzma /tmp/ccAZHRvb.o -lgcc --push-state
```

As a result, the linker notices that `-llzma` is not needed at that point in the command line and drops it.  Linking is order-sensitive.

You can fix this by using `- -llzma` instead of `-llzma -`, as [HolyBlackCat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2752075) suggested.